# ¿Como extraer el contenido de una tabla html usando python?

Tags: html, python, web, data, scraping

Estoy tratando de extraer información de una tabla en una página web, uso los módulos  BeautifulSoup y Request, logro sacar algo de información de la página, pero la tabla no. Al inspeccionar la tabla con inspeccionar elementos puedo ver el código HTML con la información que necesito, aunque en el código fuente de la página no encuentro. Supongo que esta tabla la generara algún código js. Pero la verdad no tengo ni idea.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.datos.gov.co/Salud-y-Protecci-n-Social/Casos-positivos-de-COVID-19-en-Colombia/gt2j-8ykr/data")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Hola Jose, en vez de complicarte con un scraping, ¿por qué no te descargas el JSON, CSV, EXCEL, etc con los datos?. Por ejemplo, https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/gt2j-8ykr.json? Lo puedes hacer con requests y luego parsear el documneto de forma mucho más sencilla que una tabla html.

Comment: Además, la propia página ofrece una API de acceso basa en SODA|Socrata, incluso hay ejemplos de uso para Python con Pandas: https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/www.datos.gov.co/gt2j-8ykr. Cierto que necesitarás crearte un API token para no tener limitadas las consultas, pero es la forma natural de acceder a éstos recursos. Si aún quieres seguir l camino del scraping, mirate [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/), requests no ejecuta código JS. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, si yo sé que esos datos se pueden descargar por la página, el problema es que los actualizan en la noche, y la tabla se actualiza más rápido a lo largo del día. No es muy importante, pero me entro la curiosidad del porqué no puedo sacar la información del código html, lo mismo me paso cuando intente hacer un programa que me sacara los contactos de mi wassap web.

Comment: Con requests puedes conseguir todo lo que venga directamente como html cuando cargas la página (estático), pero no lo que se genere después en el lado del cliente vía JS o mediante peticiones AJAX, etc.